# Problem in running a multithreaded code which uses Qthread in run mode

Tags: python, multithreading, pycharm, pyqt5, qthread

I used Pycharm IDE to develop a multi-threaded python program. Everything works perfectly in debug mode. The IDE generates this command line to run the program in debug mode:

```
E:\TSCExcelToolSet\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 51440 --file E:/TSCExcelToolSet/MainUserInterface.py

def initializeData(self):
    # di.CSVImporter(self.configParser.get('SectionOne', 'Path'), sqlbase.engine)
    self.progressBar.setValue(0)
    self.progressBar.setVisible(True)
    initializer = DataCollector()
    self.threadInit = QThread()
    self.threadInit.setObjectName('initThread')
    initializer.moveToThread(self.threadInit)
    # get progress messages from worker:
    initializer.sig_step.connect(self.on_worker_step)
    initializer.sig_done.connect(self.on_worker_done)
    self.sig_abort_workers.connect(initializer.abort)
    self.threadInit.started.connect(initializer.initializeData)
    self.threadInit.start()  # this will emit 'started' and start thread's event loop
```

However, when it runs in run mode it uses the below command line and the threading parts of the code does not work.

```
E:\TSCExcelToolSet\venv\Scripts\python.exe E:/TSCExcelToolSet/MainUserInterface.py
```

Moreover, when it comes to deployment, what should I do to overcome this problem.

Comment: Actually it is just related to the command line of the IDE

Comment: My problem is with "--multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 51440 --file" part of the command line which is not in run mode. Why is not included in run mode?

Comment: The multiproc parametrs is used by PyCharm to define whether multiple process should be debugged, it won't affect your application when you execute it in run mode I think...

Comment: "does not work" is not an error description suitable for a programmers' forum, please read [ask]. Also, extract and provide a [mcve].